# remove all elements of a vector of structure with the size of vector 0

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector containing structures,the data members of structure need to be removed and the size of vector changed back to 0.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct item{
unsigned int item_index;
unsigned int item_parent;
item(unsigned int index, unsigned int parent)
{
    item_index = index;
    item_parent   = parent;
}
};

class container{
std::vector<item>obj;
public:
container()
    {
      obj.push_back(item(25,2));
      obj.push_back(item(3,4));          
    }

void display()
{
    cout<<" before "<<obj[0].item_index<<endl;
    obj.clear();                               //obj.resize(0);
    cout<<" after "<<obj[0].item_index<<endl;
}
};

int main()
{
container* cont = new container();
cont->display();
return 0;
}
```

The output is before 25 after  25.  I also tried resizing the entire vector
with 0 as the new size of vector. That too produced the same output. How can I change the size of vector to 0?

Comment: You're accessing `obj` out of bounds. That is undefined behaviour. You also have a memory leak because you use `new` for no reason.

Comment: `obj.clear()`, and stop accessing elements that don't exist afterward. If you want a poke to remind you, use `obj.at(0)` instead, which will greet you with a most-accusatory reminder you're not playing nice with defined-behavior.

Comment: Although undefined behaviour and memory leak, if you insist to have an explanation, freeing a piece of memory simply means the memory is (conceptually) marked as free, and the contents of the memory may not be changed.

Comment: If you look at `obj.size()` after the `clear()` it will be `0`... that means accessing `obj[0]` is undefined behaviour, and it seems it just happens to still be occupied by the previously-populated data....

Comment: I am sorry if this is a ridiculous question, but how can I avoid the memory leak that you all are talking about?

Comment: Don't use `new`. For exampe, `container cont; cont.display();`

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to use delete container in there.

Comment: @user3124361 don't use new and delete. Memory leaks can still occur if you throw an exception.  In this case there is no need for `new`. This is not Java. Just use `container cont;`. If you really need to use pointers, use smart pointers e.g. `auto cont = std::make_unique<container>();`

Comment: yeah, I had needed to use pointer in a similar case. Thanks, I`ll be sure to check smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to print `obj.size()` before and after you clear. You will get 2 and then 0. That means the vector is cleared. The reason why you get 25 again is it still remains in memory